# Laravel Eloquent Query to 2 Million Rows takes long time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, indexing, eloquent, mariadb

I have to pull data from a table that has 2 million rows. The eloquent query looks like this:

```
$imagesData = Images::whereIn('file_id', $fileIds)
                    ->with('image.user')
                    ->with('file')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->simplePaginate(12);
```

The `$fileIds` array used in `whereIn` can contain 100s or even 1000s of file ids.

The above query works fine in small table. But in production site that has over 2 million rows in `Images` table, it takes over 15 seconds to get a reply. I use Laravel for api only.

I have read through other discussions on this topic. I changed `paginate()` to `simplePaginate()`. Some suggests perhaps having a `DB::` query with `whereRaw` might work better than `whereIn`. Some says it might be due to PDO in php while processing `whereIn` and some recommends using `Images::whereIn` which I already used.

I use MariaDB, with InnoDB for db engine and its loaded into RAM. The sql queries performs well for all other queries, but only the ones that has to gather data from huge table like this takes time.

How can I optimise the above laravel query so I can reduce down the query response to couple of seconds if possible when the table has millions of rows?

Comment: Is there an index on `file_id`? `created_at`? The relationship fields?

Comment: yeah. the migration file for this table has `file_id` indexed like this: `$table->integer('file_id')->unsigned()->index();` and  `$table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('files')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: Is `created_at` indexed?

Comment: `created_at` is added as `$table->timestamps();`.

Comment: I haven't done any further index to `created_at` other than adding it using `timestamps()`. Should I need to do anything there?

Comment: Given that you're ordering by `created_at`, you may benefit from an index on it.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I safely do that to the existing table please?

Comment: Do I need to create a migration file to edit this table and add `$table->index(['created_at', 'updated_at']);`?

Comment: You are doing it right. This looks to be an issue with your hardware. Consider upgrading it.

Comment: The hardware is pretty good. I have `RAID Policy Raid 1
Operating System    Cloud Linux
HDD Bay 1   480GB SSD
HDD Bay 2   480GB SSD
Network Bandwidth   10TB
CPU 6 Core E5-2620v2 - 2.00Ghz x2
RAM 64 GB` dedicated server. Does it mean the sql config in the server might need to be tweaked further?

Comment: I have to mention that the `$fileIds` array used in `whereIn` can contain 100s or even 1000s of file ids. Would changing it to raw queries give big performance improvement for a large table?

Comment: No, switching to raw queries is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: So does it mean the solution for this issue is more from the server's mariaDB configuration for sql queries and not from the laravel side?

Comment: could you paste the generated query? add `toSql()` and paste the query here

Comment: @Neel You do not need to index updated_at since you are not using it in the query. Alos, did adding the index improve performance? If you don't mind, could you please run an explain statement on your final query (in the database) and share with us a screenshot of the result?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL generated for the query in question.

Comment: Beware of pagination that uses `OFFSET`.

Comment: I have posted all the optimisation steps I did that resolved my issue. Thank you all for your support. Your comments helped me in digging deeper and fixing the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need indexing, which segmented your data by certain columns. You are accessing `file_id` and `created_at`. Therefore this following index will help performance.

```
$table->index(['file_id', 'created_at']);
```

Indexing will increase insert time and can make queries have weird execution plans. If you use the SQL `EXPLAIN` on the query before an after executing the query, we can verify it helps the problem.

Comment: Thank you I will try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Did you try the query? :) excited to see if it helped?

Comment: Hi @mrhn sorry for the delay. Since your post I have tried many different optimising steps. Your query did help. However, I found there was another subquery done by php by iterating the fetched results from query that was causing the biggest bottleneck and the delay. I will soon post an update before this weekend since I am now on the last step of optimising my php and will be pushing through the update tomorrow to observe the results.

Comment: I have posted all the optimisation steps I did that resolved my issue. Thank you @mrhn for your support.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an update on steps taken to speed up the page load.

1. The real culprit for such a really slow query was not the above specific query alone. After the above query fetches the data, the php iterates over the data and does a sub-query inside it to check something. This query was using the `filename` column to search the data during each iteration. Since `filename` is string and not indexed, the response time for that controller took so long since each sub-query is crawling through 1.5 millions rows inside a `foreach` loop. Once I removed this sub-query, the loading time decreased by a lot.
2. Secondly, I added the index to `file_id` and `created_at` as suggested by @mrhn and @ceejayoz above. I created a migration file like this:

   ```
   Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->index('file_id', 'created_at');
   });
   ```
3. Optimised the PHP script further. I removed all queries that does searches using `fileNames` and changed it to use the `id` to fetch results. Doing this made a huge difference throughout the app and also improved the server speed due to less CPU work during peak hours.
4. Lastly, I optimised the server by performing the following steps:

   - Completed any yum updates
   - Updated Litespeed
   - Tweaked Apache profile, this included some caching modules and installed EA-PHP 7.3
   - Updated cPanel
   - Tuned Mysql to allow your server to utilize some more of your server resources.

Once I edit all of the above steps, I found a huge difference in the loading speed. Here are the results:

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Thanks to each and everyone who have commented on this. Your comments helped me in performing all of the above steps and the result was fruitful. Thanks heaps.