# How to efficiently get all the rows of a table when the table have more than 200k rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, performance, pagination

I have more than 200k rows in a table, I need to get all the rows and perform some operations on it. I tried laravel paginator but then was facing issue iterating over each page and getting the data in the laravel backend api code

Comment: Lakh is not a common English word. Please edit your question to use numerical values. While you're at it, please also expand your question to explain in more detail what you are asking from us..

Comment: You likely want to `chunk` you results. If you can provide an example of what you want to do that will make it easier to provide an accurate solution.

Comment: It would help if you give some idea of what you mean by *perform some operations*.  Sometimes these could be done in SQL, but at the moment it's difficult to know the best way to do it.

Comment: you have to use pagination

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Query to 2 Million Rows takes long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903431/laravel-eloquent-query-to-2-million-rows-takes-long-time)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called chunk() which splits all data into separate selects, like pagination

```
User::chunk(100, function ($users) {
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    // code logic here to perform on user
  }
});
```

What it actually does is running a loop of selecting 100 entries, then doing updates with them, and then another 100 entries, another update and so on. Which means that at no point there is a huge amount of data taken from the database – you are working with a chunk of entries, not the whole table.